# Sequence Recurence Relation problem help

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]$$a_1=1,\quad a_{n+1}=(a_n)^4.$$

Hi can someone help me with this sequence?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I get "1" for all of them is that right?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: what are $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$?  Do you see a pattern?

Comment: are they all "1" ?